# images inside the blog posts

Tags: html, css

I'd like to define the appearance of my images inside the section (I'm trying to add a border to the image - but I can't reference the image directly because the images are added dynamically - as content of blog posts.)
Can you advise me on how to do that?
Do I have to create a new section/id/div? How can I than say to the machine: In the section/id/div I created I would like you to apply these styls to the images."
?
thanks, D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to get a reference to the image or the block in which the images is going to be displayed. Then apply the css rules to the image or block you will then get the styles on the image. I would prefer `class=""` if there are many and `id=""` if there is only one.

If you have img inside any elements like below,

```
<div class="someclass">
     <img src="" />
</div>
```

then at CSS,

```
.someclass{
    your rules go here.    
}
```

or if you want to directly have styles on image then you HTMl will be like below and CSS same as above.

```
<img class="someclass" src="" />
```

Comment: vini, is it possible to dynamically add link to the image? - something like adding styles to the dynamically added images.

Comment: Yes. Just use <a href=""><img class="someclass" src="" /> </a>.

Comment: then dynamically generaed content goes into css?

Comment: The line which I showed above will be a part of dynamically generated code. I didn't understand "then dynamically generaed content goes into css?" clearly. And If I have understood, then just don't worry, the css will be added to your dynamically generated code.

Comment: this is the situation: when a user clicks on the BLOG page in my web site, then the short description of every blog post is displayed - teaser with few sentences and image (if the admin has placed the image inside the teaser). I would like to make that when a user clicks on the teaser image - he is redirected to the full article - blog post. Images are generated dynamically of course inside the teaser

Comment: You can do it using two ways, one is with <a> or else by using javascript's windlow.location function with onclick event handler on image. Better to go with <a> if your are unaware of javascript. Now, No matter with what way you are doing it, just select the right way of giving css styles. And make sure that, if you are using <a> then it should be generated dynamically as the image. CSS is completely unaware whether it is dynamically generated or a simple static one it just gets applied to.

Answer (score 1):

If content is added dynamically, styles are applied automatically as new content is added to the DOM, you don't need to worry about that. Inject the content you want, and as long as there is CSS-rules that match that content, the browser will handle the rest.

**Update**

I realize that I might have misunderstood your question at first. If the user is completely in control of the markup of the blog post, I guess the best way would be to use a selector, that select every image within a container that wrap each blog post.

Lets say each blog post is rendered within an element with class `post`. Then you could do something like this:

```
.post img {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I don't have css defined. That's the problem - how and what do I have to define

Comment: thanks Christofer for your answer. I was looking something what vini suggested above.